# cURL gives Couldn't resolve host

Tags: php, curl

I am on my new dedicated server and i am gettin error on curl connections.

I tried that one

```
$_h = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.beatport.com/catalog/labels/detail?id=14248&format=json&v=1.0' ); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false ); 
curl_setopt($_h, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 ); 
var_dump(curl_exec($_h)); 
var_dump(curl_getinfo($_h)); 
var_dump(curl_error($_h));
```

and i got

```
bool(false) array(21) { ["url"]=> string(72) "http://api.beatport.com/catalog/labels/detail?id=14248&format=json&v=1.0" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } } string(40) "Couldn't resolve host 'api.beatport.com'"
```

that may be a DNS issue ?

SOLVED:

i opened /etc/hosts and added the ip of the website that i want to retrieve via curl and it worked !

Comment: Could be a firewall issue..is your server allowed to make outgoing connections?

Comment: have you tried pinging the domain? Might be outbound proxy? I've seen this before on hosts for outbound security.

Comment: it connects smtp.com for smtp relays without any problem, how can i check if its allowed

Comment: Definitely a DNS issue...you should not have to modify your local hosts file. I would suggest removing that entry and figuring out why the lookup failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is OK. This is actually an DNS configuration problem on the dedicated server. Check that your hosting service permits outgoing curl connections.

Comment: is there any fix for this or nothing to do if hosting service doesnt allow ?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem with Code Igniter code. My server is in DigitalOcean.

**My solution is restart server.** it

> service apache2 restart

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Curl couldn't resolve host while nslookup in command line worked fine. I tried apachectl restart - didn't work. stopped apache and started it again - that fixed it. I guess service apache2 restart is different than apachectl restart

Comment: Restarting apache on Mac can be done like this `sudo apachectl restart`