# Yii curl Couldn't resolve host error CentOs 6

Tags: php, curl, yii, centos

I've gotten trouble around the error `"Couldn't resolve host '...'"`.
I have also researched through many topics and couldn't find the workaround.

First time, same the code, I could do `curl` without no problem. But today it suddenly stopped working. Here were my attempts

1. Same the code in my localhost, `curl` worked fine.
2. In my server `CentOs 6` (using `Cpanel` Whm), my structure of directories looks like following

   - public_html
   - -YiiWebsiteFolder
   - -curl_test.php

I could run `curl` to same URL in `curl_test.php` without the problem, it worked fine. It also worked even I put the `curl_test.php` inside the YiiWebsiteFolder, so problem wouldn't not be the permission.

But if I run same code to call `curl` through `Yii` (YiiWebsiteFolder), ran it in Yii controller and action, it would raise the error `'Couldn't resolve host ...'.`
(my URL rewrite is very normal, my site URL looks like "`mydomain.com/index.php/test/myaction`" )

So I guessed the cause could be `Yii`, was not [DNS problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541479/curl-gives-couldnt-resolve-host) like some help topics said.

http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/file_get_contents-couldnt-resolve-host-name-120065.html

[Couldn't resolve host and DNS Resolution failed](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=29933)

Both Yii config `main.php` files of my local machine and my server are same.

Edited: I have found this guy who had same problem like me

[cURL doesn't work when it's used in a PHP application and running > through a web browser](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=78849)

> cURL doesn't work when it's used in a PHP application and running
>   through a web browser. However, that same PHP page with cURL, when run
>   via the terminal, does what it's supposed to do and fetches the
>   information that I want

But he has found it out the problem is the DAEMON array, but I don't use Apache DAEMON (even I don't sure what it is).

I have tried all of possible solutions such as restarting my network and my apache to change the order when they started, modify `etc/resolv.conf` / (add or remove 12.0.0.1 and try some public DNS)

> service network stop
>
> service network start
>
> service network restart
>
> /sbin/service httpd stop
>
> /sbin/service httpd start

I've spent many hours to troubleshoot the problem but no succeed at all.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: There wasn't answer for this question and I have to re-setup my server. Hope someone can post a workaround that will be useful with someone who get same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve your specific problem but I thought I should post to say I had the same problem in that PHP cURL could not resolve any host name when the PHP script was run from a web browser but the same script run from the terminal command line worked fine (i.e. cURL resolved host names to return the expected response). In my case it was resolved with the following:

/sbin/service httpd stop

/sbin/service httpd start